# mv all files with different extention to a new directory with new filename and same extention

Tags: ubuntu, mv

could anyone tell my how I could make a script for moving files (filename given but all possible extentions) to another new directory with new filename but same extentions.

f.e. (dir or filename could have blanks in it)

```
     dir1/m.mobi
     dir1/m.epub
```

should be moved to

```
     newdir/dir1/9989.mobi
     newdir/dir1/9989.epub
```

I have tried this.

```
     mv "./dir1/m".* "./newdir/dir1/9989.*"
```

but I get the error that `./newdir/dir1/9989.* is not a directory`.

WHere is my bug?

EDIT: I found that I could do a rename first  with `rename 's/m/9989/' m.*` 
Thanks
Walter

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: this

```
   rename 's/m/9989/' ./dir1/m.* &&  mv ./dir1/9989.* ./newdir/dir1/
```